# Do I need a transit visa for a connecting flight transfer in Heathrow?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, lhr, ukrainian-citizens

I (Ukrainian) am traveling to the USA via Heathrow in London, UK (LHR). I was a little confused from reading the UK govt website, I'm not sure if my transfer is "airside" or not.

More details:

- My layover is 3 hours, arriving in terminal 3, departing terminal 5
- My baggage is checked to my final destination.
- I have a valid US B1/B2 Visa and a EU Residence permit.

Do I need to apply for a transit visa?

Comment: You can use this UK government website to [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa)

Comment: I looked over those posts - I'm not sure if my transfer counts as "airside" or not

Comment: There are airside facilities to transfer between terminals, if your baggage is checked through without having to claim and recheck it.

Comment: Ah ok. In that case I don't think I need a transit visa. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are travelling on a reasonable route to the U.S. with a valid U.S. visa.